# Render select options according to condition knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, knockout.js, drop-down-menu

I have dropdown in my html page where I have some conditions I want to render the  of select according to the those conditions.

```
I have tried something like this:
   <select>
       <!-- ko if:  condition() -->
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <!-- /ko -->
       <!-- ko ifnot:  condition() -->
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <!-- /ko -->
       <select>
```

but this is not working for me. Anyone please help

Comment: it's working: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ww8trzew/1/). Sure you have acces to `condition` there? You have error messages?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide `option` on the basis of their values. In your case, you are showing `<option value="1">1</option>` if condition is true else hiding it. so try below code

```
if(condition)
  $('select option[value=1]').show();
else
  $('select option[value=1]').hide();
```

Comment: thanks bro. but hide of dropdown option is not working in all browsers. and this not related with knockout too. I want to render accordingly

Comment: which are the browsers in not working, can you specify?

Comment: Please try with condition as true and !condition with false values. like:-  if: true and ifnot true. or something like if else

Comment: or like this:- if: condition() == 1. and other one with else or ifnot: condition() == 1

Comment: without any toggle button it should be on page load. It should be Just check the condition and render the required html markup

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle link with knock.js and other code so that I can help you better

Comment: Actually condition() value is selected tab that could be 1, 2. So I want result in case of if: condition() == 1  or ifnot: condition() == 1. Sorry bro I am unable to write in fiddle because that have some server side code. condition is comparing with server side value.